# temporal testing API in scala

Tags: scala, testing, integration-testing, temporal

Is there a testing library faciliating testing of concurrent systems? I am looking for something that is to akka test what scalatest/scalacheck/mohito was to traditional unit tests.

I would like to view the system as independent actors emiting events (not tied to akka actors) and be able to mock any subset of them and observe the reactions of others (high level observable events emmited will suffice). Of course what is an 'actor' and 'event' will vary considerably by case, so I expect extensible classes which let me define them, and a concise DSL for declarative expressing of properties such as 'eventually fi(x)', 'if e1 then within period e2' and a scalacheck-like generator of cases/event streams, so I can request generating random events at randomized intervals (within a specified distrubtion).

Comment: You have alternative option to check is  https://github.com/mkotsur/restito

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look!